# i have kubuntu and want to install windows 7 in a dual boot

Tags: dual-boot

Currently I have installed Kubuntu 14.04 native on a machine with 1TB of disk space.

Now  I have to use a program for work which is not working in Linux nor will it run in Windows inside of a VM.

Much to my regret I need to create a separate partition and install MS Windows (dual boot) just so I can run this program.

Or I will have to buy a separate Windows machine just to run this program (which I can not afford to do ) or switch this machine to a full windows only which I do not want to do.

Answer (score 0):

**1.** open a terminal ( `Ctrl+Alt+T`)

**2.** Launch `gparted` using `sudo gparted`

**3.** Click at your *root partition* and use the right mouse button to open the menu.
Now click at the option *move or resize*

**4.** get about *10 to 20 gig* free disk space by resizing your partition (if you have got a home partition, resize the home partition.)

**5.** create your Windows partitions in the free space

**6.** Apply the changes by clicking at the `apply` button and close `gparted`

**7.** run `sudo update-grub`

**8.** restart your machine using `sudo shutdown -r now`

**9.** install windows

**10.** start ubuntu and run `sudo update-grub` in a new terminal.